# how to change the .from on the email I sent using vba for gmail?

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

I am sending email using a CDO.Message on vba from my gmail account.
all works fine, however, on my

```
With Mail
    .From
```

I am inserting the email address I want to send it from. When it arrives, it arrives with the email address itself and not the name associated to the gmail account:
.from = johndoe@gmail.com => the email will be received from "johndoe@gmail.com" instead of John Doe as defined on the gmail account.

Is there any way to get the name instead of the email address?

thanks,

all works fine except this detail.

```
     With Mail
               .Subject = subj
               .From = Range("acct").Value
               .To = dest
               '.To = Range("mailing").Offset(i, 0).Value
               .textbody = body
               If att = "" Then GoTo noatt
               attnb = 1
               While Not IsEmpty(Range("attachement").Offset(attnb, 0))
              .AddAttachment (Range("attachement").Offset(attnb, 0)) 'To attach Documents in mail
             attnb = attnb + 1
            Wend
noatt:
            End With
            'to send the mail
            Mail.Send
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following syntax:

```
Name Surname <mymail@gmail.com>
```

So in your code it would be like:

```
.From = "John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>"
```

It should do the tricks.

Hope it helps.